# An object reference when adding to a datagrid

Tags: c#

I know this is probably very simple, I have googled but still can't see my error.

**My basic code is:**

```
public static void postToImgur(string imagFilePath, string apiKey, string apiSecret, string title, string description)
{
    byte[] imageData;
    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(imagFilePath);
    imageData = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    fileStream.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
    fileStream.Close();

    const int MAX_URI_LENGTH = 32766;
    string base64img = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < base64img.Length; i += MAX_URI_LENGTH)
    {
        sb.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(base64img.Substring(i, Math.Min(MAX_URI_LENGTH, base64img.Length - i))));
    }

    string uploadRequestString = "client_id" + apiKey + "client_secret" + apiSecret + "&title=" + title + "&imageTitle" + title + "&description" + description + "&caption=" + title + "img" + "&image=" + sb.ToString();

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.xml");
    // needs a space between
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + apiKey);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());

    streamWriter.Write(uploadRequestString);
    streamWriter.Close();

    WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

    //received response is a xml file. the link to the uploaded file is in between the tag< link ></ link >
    //using regular expression to retrive the link to the image.
    Regex regex = new Regex("<link>(.*)</link>");
    var test = regex.Match(responseString).Groups[1].ToString();
    //return regex.Match(responseString).Groups[1].ToString();
    dgView.Rows.Add(test);
}

private void btnPostToImgur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // validation

    postToImgur(txtBoxImageLocation.Text, "ccc8d227d", "5b64c6b63908aa3e51840db3ce874137d7", txtBoxTitle.Text, txtBoxDescription.Text);
}
```

I'm getting the error

> an object reference is required to access non-static method or
>   property

When I try to add data to the `dgView` my datagrid variable name, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: Try : dgView.Rows.Add(new object[] {test});  the Add method for a datagrid must be a new object array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `postToImgur` is a static method. From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx):

> Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and
>   events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance
>   variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method
>   parameter.

You have tried to use

`dgView.Rows.Add(test);`

However, you have not passed the `DataGridView` object as a parameter and the variable is not static - therefore, you cannot access the `dgView` variable inside the static method.

Your two options are:

1. Make the method `postToImgur` non-static
2. Pass the `dgView` variable to the method

Comment: Thank you Nikola non-static it is :)